# adding an array into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I know that I am doing something silly here but I am trying to write my first piece of code using Java Arraylists and I have got myself confused.

Basically I have created an Arraylist called allPays.  This is going to be an array list of employee pay for each month of the year.  So if I have 10 employees then the array list will contain 10 arrays of 12 months pay.

I have then created my first array of 12 months pay.

I then try and call a method to add the array to the Arraylist.

Put it is not compiling …… can anyone guide me on where I am going wrong.  Sorry that this appears basic but I am finding it a challenging concept.

```
    package christmas;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Pays {

        public static void main(String[] args) {


        ArrayList allPays = new ArrayList<Double>();

        double[] employeePay = {10.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8,0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0};

        addtothearray(employeePay);

         }


        public static void addtothearray(double[] Pay) {


        allPays.add(Pay);

        }
     }
```

Comment: take a look in here to understand how it works: https://www.journaldev.com/744/java-array-of-arraylist-of-array

Comment: `ArrayList allPays` is a raw-type. **Don't** use raw-types.

Comment: Do you want to add all elements of the array or do you want to have an ArrayList od arrays?

Answer (score 3):

`java.util.Collections.addAll(list, array)`

Answer (score 1):

**Adding to an existing List**
* if your List is type of `Double`

```
List<Double> allPays = new ArrayList<>();
double[] employeePay = {10.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8,0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0};
DoubleStream.of(employeePay).forEach(allPays::add);
```

**Adding to an existing List**
* if your List is type of `double[]`

```
List<double[]> allPays = new ArrayList<>();
double[] employeePay = {10.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8,0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0};
allPays.add(employeePay);
```

Comment: The OP asked for solution for `List`. If exact amount is known, there is no advantages using `ArrayList` of `double[]` over `double[10][12]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Pays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<double[]> allPays = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        double[] employeePay = { 10.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8, 0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0 };
        addtothearray(allPays, employeePay);

        // Test
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString((double[]) allPays.get(0)));
    }

    public static void addtothearray(ArrayList<double[]> allPays, double[] pay) {
        allPays.add(pay);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[10.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 0.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not compile because the variable in the method addtothearray is a local variable in the main method. Passing it as an argument or making it a global variable will solve that compilation problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList allPays = new ArrayList<Double>();
    double[] employeePay = {10.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8,0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0};
    addtothearray(allPays, employeePay);
}

public static void addtothearray(ArrayList allPays, double[] Pay) {
    allPays.add(Pay);
}
```

Comment: Please make sure that your answer is well-formaten before posting.

Comment: You are right, I just pasted the original code, but never attempted to format it properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to getting the outcome you wanted, the problem is that your `ArrayList<double>` is defined to accept individual values of type double (example: 5.765) not double arrays (example: {5.5, 5.7, 3.2, etc.} ).

To fix this use `ArrayList<double[]>` instead.

You might also have trouble with the `addtothearray()` function, as you have not passed the location of the ArrayList to it.

You can fix this by changing the function parameters like this:

```
public static void addtothearray(ArrayList<double[]> allPays, double[] Pay) {
```

then pass in the allPays ArrayList when the function is called like this:

```
addtothearray(allPays, employeePay);
```